# Left outer join returning extra records

Tags: sql-server, transactions, left-join

I have 2 tables namely "Item" and "Messages".

Item table has the columns like  Id, Amount, etc.

Messages table has the columns like ItemId, Count, Comment, etc.

Here the common link between these 2 tables is the "Id" from Item and "ItemId" from Messages.

The "Count" column in the Messages table is just the count of comments per ItemId. i.e. When user updates the comment for any record, an entry gets created in the Messages table and Count for that particular ItemId shows as 1. If user updates one more comment to same record, the Count shows 2 and so on. If user does not update comment for a certain record, the entry does not get created in Messages table at all (NULL).

I want to capture all the records from the Item table irrespective of whether user has updated comment or not.  If there are 0 comments, the query should return NULL in the Comments column for that record. But, If the user has updated the comment, it should pick up the comment having the highest "Count". E.g. if one record has 8 comments, the query should return only the record where Messages.Count=8 and not all 8 records. If only one comment, then that comment should be seen.

I have written LEFT OUTER JOIN but not able to get through as it shows all 8 records. In the results, I find 7 records with NULL as the count and the 8th record showing count as 8 but I need only this 8th record and not the other 7.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Below is my query:

```
Select 
Id,
Amount,
Messages.Comment As Comments
From Item
Left Outer Join Messages ON Messages.ItemId=Item.Id
Left Outer Join (Select ItemId, MAX(Id) as max_id from Messages Group by ItemId) T ON Messages.ItemId=T.ItemId and Messages.Id=T.max_id
Where amount > 100
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. [Here](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) is a great place to start.

Comment: To expand (a little) on Sean's point, your question doesn't include enough useful detail for us to help you. Check out [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and the importance of a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). After that, [Start Here](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to edit your question as needed.(Same link as above.)

Comment: Hi. Please read & act on [mcve]. Also hits googling 'stackexchange homework'. (It doesn't matter whether you would call this homework.) Show that your program calculates what you expect it to as it goes through (sub)expressions--including that arguments passed to each function/operator meet its requirements--by saying what that is & showing that it actually does it via incremental output. Part of justifying "minimal is finding a working example for maximal partial functionality. Ask about the (small) difference between the examples. (Basic debugging.) PS This is not clear re desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've hooked up an example using temp tables which I think covers what you're looking for. Just remove the temp table stuff and replace with your actual tables and it should work.

```
CREATE TABLE #Item (    ID int PRIMARY KEY,
            Amount numeric(9,2))

CREATE TABLE #Messages (    ItemId int REFERENCES #Item(ID),
            [Count] smallint,
            Comment nvarchar(max))


INSERT INTO #Item (ID, Amount)
SELECT 1, 100
UNION  
SELECT 2, 120
UNION 
SELECT 3, 140
UNION
SELECT 4, 50

INSERT INTO #Messages ( ItemID,
            [Count],
            Comment)
SELECT 1, 1, 'Comment 1 - 1'
UNION 
SELECT 1, 2, 'Comment 1 - 2'
UNION
SELECT 2, 1, 'Comment 2 - 1'
UNION
SELECT 2, 1, 'Comment 3 - 1'
UNION
SELECT 2, 2, 'Comment 3 - 2'

SELECT  I.Id,
    I.Amount,
    M.Comment
FROM    #Item AS I
    OUTER APPLY (   SELECT  TOP 1 M.Comment
            FROM    #Messages AS M
            WHERE   M.ItemId = I.ID
            ORDER BY    M.[Count] DESC) AS M
WHERE   i.amount > 100

DROP TABLE #Messages
DROP TABLE #Item
```

Answer (score 0):

go for it bro....

```
 Select 
    Id,
    Amount,
    T.Comment As Comments
    From Item
    Left Outer Join (Select ItemId, MAX(Id) as max_id, Comments from Messages Group by ItemId) T ON Item.ItemId=T.ItemId
    Where amount > 100
```